# why the CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowFarneback () method uses a lot of memory ?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I use a CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowFarneback() method to calculate the optical flow. But as a result, it uses a lot of memory and the program runs slowly. How to fix it ? 
Thank you for your responses !

```
public class OpticalFlow : BaseFilter
{
    private Mat prevFrame;
    private long frameCount;
    private bool oldFrameEmpty = true;
    public OpticalFlow()
    {
        TAG = "[Optical Flow Test]";
    }

    protected override Mat ProcessFrame(ref Mat frame)
    {
        frameCount++;
        Mat rez = new Mat();
        frame.CopyTo(rez);
        Mat nextFrame = new Mat();


        CvInvoke.CvtColor(frame, nextFrame, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
        if (!oldFrameEmpty)
        {
            Image<Gray, byte> prev0 = prevFrame.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
            Image<Gray, byte> next0 = nextFrame.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
            Image<Gray, Single> flowX = new Image<Gray, Single>(rez.Width, rez.Height);
            Image<Gray, Single> flowY = new Image<Gray, Single>(rez.Width, rez.Height);

            CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowFarneback(prev0, next0, flowX, flowY, 0.5, 3, 20, 20, 7, 1.5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.OpticalflowFarnebackFlag.FarnebackGaussian);

            prevFrame = nextFrame.Clone();
            oldFrameEmpty = false;
        }
        if (oldFrameEmpty)
        {
            prevFrame = nextFrame.Clone();
            oldFrameEmpty = false;
        }
        return rez;
    }
```

Comment: Do any of the types you are using implement `IDisposable` (e.g `Image<>`)?

Comment: I tried to use `IDisposable` for `Image <>`. Nothing changed. @mjwills

Comment: Please show us your attempt to do that

Comment: Also, which of the types that are referenced in your code implement `IDisposable`? And which don't?

Comment: @mjwills 
The `Image<TColor, TDepth>` class automatically take care of the memory management and garbage collection.

Once the garbage collector decided that there is no more reference to the `Image<TColor, TDepth>` object, it will call the Disposed method, which release the unmanaged IplImage structure.

Comment: So your code is working well now because you added `using`?

Comment: @mjwills 
No my code works still bad. And it's not in `using`. It is the `CvInvoke.CalcOpticalFlowFarneback()` method that slows down the code.

Comment: In that case you should contact the developers of `CalcOpticalFlowFarneback` and ask them to fix it.

Comment: @mjwills
Thanks for answers !)